# How to compare two large datasets using Pandas or read_lookup() method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, lookup

I am new on Python, Pandas an learning faster, with the help of all of you. I need one more time your help, I present the situation:
I have two txt files:
the first one with data in the format:

```
85|9
8714|386
8767|24961
9180|280
930|34549
9318|349
9498|90
12876|56665
12886|24961
12989|6939
13237|205614
```

which is more than 500 rows, and the second one with data format as:

```
42|1103|0|bgp
43|1140|0|bgp
44|1239|0|bgp
45|1267|0|bgp
46|1273|0|bgp
47|1103|-1|bgp
48|1140|0|bgp
49|1239|0|bgp
50|1267|0|bgp
51|1273|0|bgp
```

To check relationship between elements file 1:

```
  if a|b = 0 or b|a = 0 : (a,b) are peers
  if a|b = -1:
         a is provider, b is customer
  else if: b|a = -1:
         b is provider, a is customer
  else: NA
```

The output of the script I want is something like:

```
customer,provider, peers, NA
0,0,1,0
1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1
...
...
```

Is it possible using pandas dataFrame, Python or any read_lookup() method?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give more explanation on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Shure, the file1 represent data-output from a server and file2 relationships or not between data on file1. Unfortunately my code does work:
`
def read_lookup(fileobj, delim = '|'):

    data = dict()
    for line in fileobj:
        if line.startswith('#'): continue
        a, b, rel = line.split(delim)
        if is_reserved(a) or is_reserved(b): continue 
        if ',' in rel: continue                       
        rel = int(rel)
        if rel == 1: continue                       
        data[a+'|'+b] = rel
        data[b+'|'+a] = rel*-1
    return data `